# how to wait for completion of volley asynchronous task in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using volley library for API calls and getting response. But i want to wait for getting complete response from API then execute rest of code below Volley request. I tried it using interfaces and also using thread but it is not working.

Please give me some suggestion for implementing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you sending request in volley, It will call you back if request is successful or any error occurred :

So You need to call a method that contains code that should be executed after getting response :

Here I have commented where you can call that method :

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, js, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Successfully signed in : " + response.toString());
                    //put your code here
// added method call
 parseJson();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    String json = null;
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error at sign in : " + error.getMessage());
                    // put your code here
                }
            });
```

**Edited** :

For executing code after json parsing :

Handler : `IncomingHandler` class

```
private static class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        private WeakReference<MainActivity> yourActivityWeakReference;

        public IncomingHandler(MainActivity yourActivity) {
            yourActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(yourActivity);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            if (yourActivityWeakReference != null) {
                MainActivity yourActivity = yourActivityWeakReference.get();

                switch (message.what) {
                    case 0:

                        // add your code here
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Create instance of it in `onCreate()`

```
// Declaration of handler
 private IncomingHandler incomingHandler;
 // initialize handler
        incomingHandler=new IncomingHandler(MainActivity.this);
```

Sample parse json method and sending message using handler :

```
 public void parseJson() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            System.out.println("Printing :" + i);
        }
        incomingHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
```

Thanks.!!

Comment: why you degrade me ?? I mentioned that i am beginner then also

Comment: @Rohan Bundelkhandi : Oh man..!! I did not degrade you instead I have given you an answer..!!

Comment: @ Rohan Bundelkhandi : You need to be clear for your application flow..!!

Comment: Thanks for answering but i am telling about degradation to person who did it, not you?

Comment: Actually my flow is following :

Comment: @Rohan Bundelkhandi : Obviously not.. Someone else.. We can not see who degrade that.. I think you are new to stackoverflow..!!

Comment: Actually my flow is following :1) I am making request and parsing that request in one separate function 2) then i have added some more code below function call 3) Problem is that when i am calling the function it is going upto JSONRequest and then not waiting for completion of response and started executing all statement below that function call and at last it is displaying JSONResponse     I want it to be wait for whole JSON Parsing then execute another code

Comment: Yes i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: @Rohan Bundelkhandi : Use handler.. When parsing is done then send message using handler ..!!

Comment: @Rohan Bundelkhandi : So just do not jump on someone unless you are sure..!!

Comment: can you write code or send me link so that i can understand it properly

Comment: I have one doubt that, suppose if i am doing JSON parsing in one function then where should i call that function?

Comment: @Rohan Bundelkhandi : At the end of function..!!